# How does SpaCy's "Matcher" (Gazetteer) format work, for the nlp.matcher.add method?

Tags: python, spacy

I've started to play around with Spacy.io's NLP package, and examined a few introductions along with some of the sample code.

I'm intrigued by the spacy.en.English.matcher.add method --  What is the format for adding my own entities? While the basic format is explained, it seems there are other features available. Can the entities I add be linked to dbpedia/wikipedia entries or other external links?

Here's the code in from the Spacy matcher example:
https://github.com/honnibal/spaCy/blob/master/examples/matcher_example.py

```
   nlp.matcher.add(
    "GoogleNow", # Entity ID: Not really used at the moment.
    "PRODUCT",   # Entity type: should be one of the types in the NER data
    {"wiki_en": "Google_Now"}, # Arbitrary attributes. Currently unused.
    [  # List of patterns that can be Surface Forms of the entity

        # This Surface Form matches "Google Now", verbatim
        [ # Each Surface Form is a list of Token Specifiers.
            { # This Token Specifier matches tokens whose orth field is "Google"
                ORTH: "Google"
            },
            { # This Token Specifier matches tokens whose orth field is "Now"
                ORTH: "Now"
            }
        ],
        [ # This Surface Form matches "google now", verbatim, and requires
          # "google" to have the NNP tag. This helps prevent the pattern from
          # matching cases like "I will google now to look up the time"
            {
                ORTH: "google",
                TAG: "NNP"
            },
            {
                ORTH: "now"
            }
        ]
    ]
)
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can link them, but that doesn't come out of the box with spaCy as far as I can tell. You can set your own category type (e.g. SINGER instead of PRODUCT; note that this is currently broken and you may need to use v0.93 for that) and then populate it with DBpedia entries (e.g. *David Bowie* instead of *Google Now*). Once you've done this, you can use a map between the entities and their URLs. Something that does the last link automatically may be coming up as this comment suggest

```
 {"wiki_en": "Google_Now"}, # Arbitrary attributes. Currently unused.
```

Answer (score 1):

With spaCy >v1, you can now [add a callback function](https://spacy.io/docs/usage/rule-based-matching#callback-functions) to the matcher.  I could imagine something like this would work for your use-case:

```
def getlink(matcher, doc, i, matches):
    spans = [(ent_id, label, doc[start : end]) for ent_id, label, start, end in matches]
    for span in spans:
        **do something to get link from wikipedia**
matcher.add_entity('David Bowie', on_match=getlink)
matcher.add_pattern('David Bowie', {ORTH: 'David'}, {ORTH: 'Bowie'}])
doc = Doc(matcher.vocab, words=[u'David', u'Bowie', u'Space', u'Oddity'])
matcher(doc)
```